# How to store a string array inside a string in java

Tags: java, string

I have a String in java

`String s = "i am {0} in IT {1} industry";` 
  and another string array is

```
String[] s1={"Java developer","software"};
```

I need to put the data of s1 inside s in place of a[0] and a[1] and s will grow according   to the data s1 having,How to do that in java,Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: `String.format()` .That's a hint to start. Exactly what you want. Goahead.

Comment: -5 ?? Don't know why so many downvotes. OP don't know about `String#Format` or any crap method. That's not a sin. @Smit have a look here :http://techtots.blogspot.in/2013/07/java-message-format-using-named.html

Comment: i am new to this please explain in a simple way

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
s = s.replace("a[0]", s1[0]).replace("a[1]", s1[1])
```

The only issue is that you have no 'a[1]' substring in your string - there just '[1]' - let's think it's just a typo.

Comment: sorry for the type mistake of a[0] its s1[0] i edited my question please check

Comment: so, use code: s = s.replace("s1[0]", s1[0]).replace("s1[1]", s1[1])

Comment: You constantly change your string in question :)
For latest version of it:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "i am {0} in IT {1} industry";
        String[] s1={"Java developer","software"};
        s = s.replace("{0}", s1[0]).replace("{1}", s1[1]);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

This code do what you want and print resulted string: "i am Java developer in IT software industry"